# Swift iOS programming access a button inside a view programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, addtarget

I'm new to iOS programming. I'm developing a custom keyboard with a custom nib file for it's view. How can I add target for buttons in the nib file without connect them manually to my UIInputViewController?
I tried this code but doesn't works!

```
class LatinKeyboard: UIInputViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad();
    let nib = UINib(nibName: "KeyboardView", bundle: nil);
    let objects = nib.instantiateWithOwner(self, options: nil)
    view = objects[0] as UIView;        

    for subview in view.subviews {
        if(subview is UIButton){
            var key = subview as UIButton;
            key.addTarget(self, action: "keyPressed:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside);
        }
    }


}



func keyPressed(sender: AnyObject?) {
    let button = sender as UIButton
    let title = button.titleForState(.Normal)
    (textDocumentProxy as UIKeyInput).insertText(title!)
}
```

}

Comment: What is not working? Is it compiling? In Xcode 7.0.1 this doesn't compile for me: let button = sender as UIButton.

Comment: It loads KeyboardView nib file and shows the loaded view. KeyboardView contains some buttons but i cannot access them as subviews of view. I don't know how i can access them and add target for them without set outlet for each button separately.

Comment: When you loop through view.subviews, how many subviews are there and can you tell what type they are?

Comment: This article looks like a great tutorial on custom keyboards. I think it is a better approach that will avoid the kind of issue you are having. http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-8-creating-a-custom-keyboard-in-swift--cms-22344

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I have seen this article. 
**how many subviews are there and can you tell what type they are?** I cannot debug or print subview counts. I don't know why! the print function works correctly in ViewController of application but not working in added keyboard file: UIInputViewController!